# How do I manage large data set spanning multiple tables? UNIONs vs. Big Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an aggregate data set that spans multiple years.  The data for each respective year is stored in a separate table named Data.  The data is currently sitting in MS ACCESS tables, and I will be migrating it to SQL Server.

I would prefer that data for each year is kept in separate tables, to be merged and queried at runtime.  I do not want to do this at the expense of efficiency, however, as each year is approx. 1.5M records of 40ish fields.

I am trying to avoid having to do an excessive number of UNIONS in the query.  I would also like to avoid having to edit the query as each new year is added, leading to an ever-expanding number of UNIONs.

Is there an easy way to do these UNIONs at runtime without an extensive SQL query and high system utility?  Or, if all the data should be managed in one large table, is there a quick and easy way to append all the tables together in a single query?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to store them in separate tables, then I would create a view that does that unioning for you.

```
create view AllData
as
(
    select * from Data2001
    union all
    select * from Data2002
    union all
    select * from Data2003
)
```

But to be honest, if you use this, why not put all the data into 1 table.  Then if you wanted you could create the views the other way.

```
create view Data2001
as
(
    select * from AllData
            where CreateDate >= '1/1/2001'
            and CreateDate < '1/1/2002'
)
```

Comment: You don't use `UNION`. You would use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: +1 for your second suggestion.  They can all be in one table, with separate views for each year.

Answer (score 0):

A single table is likely the best choice for this type of query. HOwever you have to balance that gainst the other work the db is doing.

One choice you did not mention is creating a view that contains the unions and then querying on theview. That way at least you only have to add the union statement to the view each year and all queries using the view will be correct. Personally if I did that I would write a createion query that creates the table and then adjusts the view to add the union for that table. Once it was tested and I knew it would run, I woudl schedule it as a job to run on the last day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using horizontal partitioning.

You basically create a partitioning function that informs the DBMS to create separate tables for each period, each with a constraint informing the DBMS that there will only be data for a specific year in each.

At query execution time, the optimiser can decide whether it is possible to completely ignore one or more partitions to speed up execution time.

The setup overhead of such a schema is non-trivial, and it only really makes sense if you have a *lot* of data. Although 1.5 million rows per year might seem a lot, depending on your query plans, it shouldn't be any big deal (for a decently specced SQL server). Refer to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: . . Does MS Access support horizontal partitioning?

Comment: Absolutely not, but OP suggests migration to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments due to low rep, but definitely agree with 1 table, and partitioning is helpful for large data sets, and is supported in SQL Server, where the data will be getting migrated to.

If the data is heavily used and frequently updated then monthly partitioning might be useful, but if not, given the size, partitioning probably isn't going to be very helpful.